# Send push notification via parse to your iphone as a test

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, push-notification

I implemented parse push notifications in my project and I tested it out with a test code. In viewController:

```
var push = PFPush()
       push.setMessage("This is a test")
        push.sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock({
            (isSuccesful: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            println(isSuccesful)

        })
```

and in the appDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Here is the code for parse Push notifications. 
    Parse.setApplicationId("oIqRHQ8SBqLiuFzU5fIXRKgMVTHrH4ft6Gat7BW7", clientKey: "zPJ5SpDRFg9IqgiWZmW0N3FumzEwSDK1YvPxsipl")
    var pushSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert, categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(pushSettings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    println("succesful")
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    println("failed :(")
}
```

When I launch the app, it prints successful and true. Also, on the parse.com website I can see the notifications were send. However, why can't I send a notification to my phone using the parse website? When I try to do that, it says there are no registered devices. But I did register my device (with the .p12 certificate).

What could solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you forgot is to save the deviceToken for your installation on parse. Try this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {        
    PFInstallation.currentInstallation().setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    PFInstallation.currentInstallation().saveInBackgroundWithBlock() { (success, error) in
        if error != nil {
            println("Saving failed")
        }

        if success {
            println("Saved the new device push token to parse successfully")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I add this to the AppDelegate I suppose? I am trying it out! :)

Comment: Try replacing your method with mine :p

Comment: :) you don't need to set  and save the token every time, led you would be wasting api calls. As far as I am concerned it only changes when the user reinstalls

Comment: Oh, but could I use this code in an app that I would upload in the app store?

Comment: Sure, I meant you will save API calls on parse when you don't set this every time the application registers for remote notifications

Comment: Okay, how would you suggest to change this then? Is is possible to check if the user is already registered? I am a beginner, so I ave no idea how it all works :)

Comment: As parse is saving the installation to disk you could just compare the current device token with the device token you get in the appdelegate function call that is mentioned above. If you are just playing around you can simply ignore what I said as I am rather convinced you won't be hitting the 30 req/second limit of parse

Comment: Haha, okay! I will ignore it for now! ;)